# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.lang.Iterable.iterator()' when starting a notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I noticed some of my users are getting this exception. I don't know how to reproduce it, I only have the reports on Crashlytics. Seems to be deep inside Google's code. Out of thousands who have used this code only 39 have had the exception.

Any idea what might be wrong?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.lang.Iterable.iterator()' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getUserIfProfile(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2141)
       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getUserBadgeForDensity(ApplicationPackageManager.java:997)
       at android.app.Notification$Builder.getProfileBadgeDrawable(Notification.java:2877)
       at android.app.Notification$Builder.hasThreeLines(Notification.java:3092)
       at android.app.Notification$Builder.build(Notification.java:3646)
       at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi21$Builder.build(NotificationCompatApi21.java:136)
       at android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat$LollipopExtender.build(NotificationCompat.java:504)
       at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplApi21.build(NotificationCompat.java:835)
       at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder.build(NotificationCompat.java:1752)
       at mycode.startNotification(mycode.java:361)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue, and do not have any idea of reason of it

Comment: I haven't found anything useful. I have no idea why the question was voted down either.

Comment: Are you creating the notification in background thread?

Comment: No, main thread.

Comment: Our crashlytics reports show only this happening on Android 5 and 6. I checked the code in ApplicationPackageManager and the code changed on Android 7, so it seems that this is fixed in Android 7.

Comment: You can use Java Exceptions - Try...Catch block after declaring List.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ApplicationPackageManager.java
private UserInfo getUserIfProfile(int userHandle) {
    List<UserInfo> userProfiles = getUserManager().getProfiles(UserHandle.myUserId());
    for (UserInfo user : userProfiles) {
        if (user.id == userHandle) {
            return user;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and

```
public List<UserInfo> getProfiles(int userHandle) {
    try {
        return mService.getProfiles(userHandle, false /* enabledOnly */);
    } catch (RemoteException re) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Could not get user list", re);
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, if there is something wrong with AIDL request, or user's profile is disabled you will have NPE in ApplicationPackageManager.java code. I think it is impossible to prevent this situation, and I advise you to wrap notification creation in try{}catch block

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: I cannot find this function in API 28, any ideas what happened with it?