# NotificationCompat.Builder - 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' NPE

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

This crash is occurring unpredictably. I'm not able to reproduce it.
What is a potential cause of this and how to fix it? I was thinking about try-catch but I'm not sure that will fix it.

getNotification method where crash happens:

```
Notification getNotification(){
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PrintQueueActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, GlobalSettings.CHANNEL_PRINT)
            .setContentTitle("Print Queue")//this line is 202
            .setContentText(getStatus())
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(requestError || PrintQueueServiceState.getNumberOfErroredJobs() > 0 ? R.drawable.notify_print_error : R.drawable.notify_print).build();

    return notification;
}
```

Crash only occurs when getNotification is called from this method. It's okay from others

```
private void setErrorState(boolean error){
    if(error != requestError){
        requestError = error;
        startForeground(GlobalSettings.NOTIFICATION_PRINT_QUEUE, getNotification());
        if(null != listener){
            listener.statusChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is stack trace:**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getUserIfProfile(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2588)
       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getUserBadgeForDensity(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1277)
       at android.app.Notification$Builder.getProfileBadgeDrawable(Notification.java:3009)
       at android.app.Notification$Builder.hasThreeLines(Notification.java:3234)
       at android.app.Notification$Builder.build(Notification.java:3787)
       at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatBuilder.buildInternal(SourceFile:283)
       at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatBuilder.build(SourceFile:200)
       at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder.build(SourceFile:1505)
       at uk.co.app.printing.PrintQueueService.getNotification(SourceFile:202)
       at uk.co.app.printing.PrintQueueService.setErrorState(SourceFile:258)
       at uk.co.app.printing.PrintQueueService.access$000(SourceFile:49)
       at uk.co.app.printing.PrintQueueService$2.onError(SourceFile:221)
       at uk.co.app.webservice.WebServiceTask.onPostExecute(SourceFile:197)
       at uk.co.app.webservice.WebServiceTask.onPostExecute(SourceFile:42)
       at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
       at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6134)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Stats from crashlytics
[image: Stats from crashlytics]

Comment: Seems to be the same issue as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123466/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-interface-method-java-util-it), looks like there is not really a way to fix it. Wrapping it in try catch will prevent the crash, but will probably cause the notification to not show.